# Firebase Non-Purchaser Android Audience Targeting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to target my android users that did not have an `in_app_purchase` across their entire lifetime. I created the following audience in the "Firebase Analytics Audiences"-dashboard, but could unfortunately not save and create the audience. The `in_app_purchase` can't be `Count < 1`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing and talking to the Firebase support team, I found out that it is possible to target non-purchasers directly within the Firebase Audience-section through LTV (`in_app_purchase Count < 1` have not yet been implemented for Firebase).

[image]

Comment: You saved a life today :)

Comment: With the new audience builder it is possible to exclude users. You could include any user who has opened the app at least once (you need to include some users), and then exclude all users with `in_app_purchase.count > 0`.